# Login problem with Safari on single machine

Tags: control-panel, login

I'm having the strangest problem.

I have ExpressionEngine 2.5.2 site using Zoo Visitor to manage my members. I have multiple accounts setup so i can test the site from different member ship groups.

From my machine Mac 10.8.2 with Safari 6.0.2 everything works fine. I can login/logout on both frontend and control panel in both Safari, FF and Chrome. My client with the exact same software versions however can't.

His machine refuses to login while using safari, firefox shows none of these problems. On the frontend i'm able to login when a select the auto_login function. But without selecting that, no dice.

On the backend I have the same problem, until i switch the admin_session_type to cookie only. And then i'm only able to login when i select the auto_login function.

This however isn't a solution because i want to be running the backend using admin_session_type Session ID + Cookies.

## This i've already tried

- Removing securit:ee
- Security and Session Preferences -> Require IP Address and User Agent for Login?
- Security and Session Preferences -> Allow multiple log-ins from a single account?
- Checking apache/php logs and error logs

Does any of you have a clue in what direction i should be looking?

Comment: Its not you its me. given your detail it is a 99% probability that its your clients machine. It could be proxy, network, cache, cookies etc. I'd be looking at the machine over EE, whilst you say the machine is identical, I'd wager there is something amiss at their end. Have them install another browser, if pain persists its likely a network issue, if not then a Safari issue, on their machine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was found by the client when he tried to login to mailchimp. Their system warned him that his SYSTEM CLOCK was set into the future. After adjusting this all problems disappeared.

So not to self: in case of strange login behavior check the system clock and date.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue too. it looks as if it starts to happen when you are auto logged out when your session expires. 
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/102628/

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/233088/

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/219020/#1038039

Comment: Nice find Jelle, expect to pay EE $45 to address an EE issue ;-)